# After logging into MySQL 5.6 successfully as root, it says access denied for root, ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: mysql, macports, mysql5

I recently used MacPorts to upgrade from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6.  I can use my database fine on my laptop.  I tried to enable remote access to the database so I could edit the database using DB clients on other computers on my network, but **after I logged in as root OK, it said access denied for root**:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 31
Server version: 5.6.19 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have tried the answer posted [mysql how to fix Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) and it does not fix the problem

Comment: @duDE I tried the answer from the question you think this is a duplicate of, and it did not fix the problem.

Comment: The problem is NOT that I can't login as root.  I can!  The problem is that AFTER logging in as root, I can't get the GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES... command to work.

Comment: Run mysqld with --skip-grant-tables and then login and grant yourself perms.

Comment: try this 
`CREATE USER ‘username‘@’host_machine‘ IDENTIFIED BY ‘some_pass‘;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ‘username‘@’host_machine‘WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER ‘username‘@’%’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘password‘;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ‘username‘@’%’WITH GRANT OPTION;`