# Screwed something when trying to fix mysql 'acces denied for root' with no password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, passwords, mysql

After updating Ubuntu 16.04 with new updates, my java app could not connect to mysql anymore.
I tried to connect manually via terminal, and with Mysql Workbench, same result :

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Usually I log in with user root and no password.
After some searching, I found that that's something to do with `plugin auth`

I followed the instruction on [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost), the [second answer](https://superuser.com/a/1129234/257269)

```
sudo mysql -u root
use mysql;
[mysql] update user set plugin='' where User='root';
[mysql] flush privileges;
```

But I didn't check my `mysql` version beforehand, which is 5.7.17.
I know, I tried to do quick and I did stupid.
I Should have done :

```
[mysql] update user set plugin='mysql_native_password' where User='root';
```

So now, I can't even launch any `mysql` prompt to correct my error.
I can't find if user "mysql" can connect via prompt ...
I can't remember if I have set other users: how can I verify this ?

Any idea somebody, please ?

Comment: Welcome on superuser. I fixed some link. Please [edit] your post if the link to the second answer is not correct (you can take the link from question or answer from the share text below the post). Remember to add a "double space" to have a newline...

Answer (score 0):

after searching a bit more, I stumbled upon this, which did the trick ;

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -h localhost
```

From there , I could connect to mysql. Then :

```
update user set plugin='mysql_native_password' where user = 'root';
```

After restarting the service I could connect with root user.