# Cannot login to MySQL, access denied

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

After a crash, I re-installed Ubuntu on my dev machine over the previous installation, and after I re-installed all the necessary packages (including mysql-server and mysql-client) I went on restoring the dev database. Unfortunately, I am unable to connect.

This works :

```
$ sudo su
# mysql -u root
```

this does not

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

- I have tried purging `mysql-*` and reinstalling everything.
- I have tried reconfiguring (i.e. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7`)
- I have tried manually reseting the password using `UPDATE` queries.
- I have tried everything [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset) (ecept that the table `user` does not have a `password` column, but an `authentication_string` one)

Please, can someone help me get this thing working?

---

### ** Edit **

```
mysql> SELECT user, host, authentication_string, password_expired, account_locked FROM user WHERE user = 'root';
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+----------------+
| user             | host      | authentication_string | password_expired | account_locked |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+------------------+----------------+
| root             | localhost | *<password hash>      | N                | N              |
| root             | %         | *<password hash>      | N                | N              |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Both `root` users have the same password, set using `PASSWORD('password')`, and all privileges have been flushed, then the service was restarted.

Contrary to what the documentation says, running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7` does **not** prompt me to specify a new password for root. The command terminates successfully, but I am never asked to specify a password.

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer, [here](https://superuser.com/a/1129234/41727).

Basically, the `plugin` value for the user `root@'localhost'` was not `mysql_native_password`.

```
UPDATE user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

worked, and I was finally able to log in without super user privileges.

Comment: I have same problem but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL permissions were probably not restored.  The fact that you can log into the server without any permissions suggests that you need to set the root password, and add any other users that need to be used with their respective permissions.

Comment: A password has been set for `root`, but I can still log in to mysql console without a password in super user mode (i.e. root). But if I specify the `root` user in "normal" mode, the password set for that user is ignored and I still get an access denied.